# Twitterizer suddenly stopped working

Tags: c#, twitter, twitterizer

I've a c# winforms application that uses twitter api using the twitterizer library. The app was working fine last week but today all requests are returning `Unauthorized` as result.

I tried the same credentials with a php library and it looks good. I have done a lot of debugging and am pretty sure that the problem is with twitterizer.

I know twitterizer is no longer supported but is there any way i can get my app getting working as soon as possible without having to implement a new library for all the functions i have to use?

I fiddled and this is the request that twitterizer is sending:

```
GET /1.1/account/verify_credentials.json HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Twitterizer/2.4.2.32115
Authorization: OAuth realm="Twitter API",oauth_consumer_key="CONSUMER_KEY",oauth_nonce="21555892",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1389894564",oauth_token="OAUTH_TOKEN",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="Lrfxw7AnKZXv%2BxWitFkT9%2BIfMtY%3D"
Host: api.twitter.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What response are you getting? Print out both the response and the status of the connection to provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the latest code from git hub (develop branch), compile it then copy and paste the newly compiled dll's over the existing twitterizer dll's in your project. This is how I just resolved the same issue. I tried updating through nu get first, but it did not fix the problem.

Git Hub Url: https://github.com/Twitterizer/Twitterizer/tree/develop

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Twitterizer doesn't support Twitter API 1.1, so it stopped working when Twitter ceased the support for their old API 1.0. Since I had the same problem (I was using Twitterizer in an old .NET 3.5 application) I switched to TweetSharp, which AFAIK is the only library available for .NET 3.5 (and also 2.0) with Twitter API 1.1 support.

For further information you can [read my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27449299/1233379).

I can personally guarantee that it works because I used it in an old 3.5 project and I managed to make it work (in fact it saved my day).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was able to use Twitterizer with API 1.1 until this problem came up. Now, I'm using TweetInvi library and it's a great library and a very well maintained project. However, only works with .Net 4.0 and above.

Comment: I see: I'll stick to TweetSharp for now since it works with .NET 3.5 aswell :)